# Should I use states to implement menu and screens for an application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am making a game. And this time trying to implement menu (-->tutorial) -> game-> scoreboard -> game over
screens.

These screens themselves are quite different in terms of structure. So i am not sure if states is a 100% correct approach here (as I understand states are good for similar layouts) From the other hand many of them has back button to return to previous state, e.g. in tutorial I will have start game and back to menu buttons, etc.

I wonder if there is a clear solution for a problem like this? Maybe there is a special library to handle such cases?

Answer (score 0):

[State machines](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/finite-state-machines-for-ai-in-actionscript) (not only for visual states) are a good solution to implement the behavior of encapsulated components, such as buttons or - in your case - menu items, perhaps even some of your game logic. They can be described independently for each component, and they help to keep your interactions organized, and thus to prevent errors.

State machines are difficult to maintain, however, when you are looking at an entire application: The interactions are usually multi-dimensional (i.e. not only one component is involved, but many, and at different levels in the hierarchy), and when all the different players are taken into account, the resulting state machine will soon become very complex.

From my experience, it is best to use an event-driven approach combined with Model-View-Controller architecture for your application logic, and use state machines at the component level.  I would advise to look at some of the existing Model-View-Controller frameworks for this, most notably [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/), [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) and [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) (though to me, Parsley seems a little less complete than the other two).